# Converting varchar column to datetime when multiple formats were used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column startDate in tbMyTable that was set up incorrectly as a varchar.  Most of the data in this column is good, but multiple datetime formats are used.  A few rows of the table just have junk in the column.

Please help me write a sql script that will convert the column from varchar(50) to a nullable DateTime - saving the data that can be converted and setting the bad data to null.

Ken

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What formats? If mixed `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` this isn't actually posssible.

Comment: How much data are you talking about?  It may make sense to export the table, massage it with a proper scripting language and importing it again.

Answer (score 2):

Check this t-sql script (its works with different string dates format):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(a.field) = 1 THEN CONVERT (DATETIME, a.field, 101) ELSE NULL END field
FROM (
    SELECT '2012-06-06' as field
    UNION
    SELECT null as field
    UNION
    SELECT '2012-06-06asdad' as field
    UNION
    SELECT '2012/06/06' as field 
) a
```

For more information of the **CONVERT** function check this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The function **ISDATE** returns 1 when is a valid date.